# Can a Thermostat Common Wire (C-Wire) Be Added to a DNV40NB Heater?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat

During recent renovations, we had to move our existing thermostat. Instead of replacing it with the same dumb 2-wire knob (white/red), I'd like to get a smart thermostat like the ecobee3. All of these new thermostats require a C-line, yet my heater does not have one currently. Can I add one to it?

Details:

- [Ecobee3](https://support.ecobee.com/hc/en-us/articles/227874667-Heat-only-2-wire-boiler-furnace-installations)
- Heater: [DNV40NB](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf/4/387/38673-desa/dnv25nb.pdf?d64875da319bbf377efffbb723705db6)
- Board wiring schematics:

[image]

Lastly, if it is possible to add a C-wire to this board, is it something a licensed electrician would need to do, or is it safe for a tinkerer like myself to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  I've highlighted the `C` wire in the wiring diagram.

[image: DNV40NB Wiring Diagram]

You'll have to bring a wire from the transformer in the heater, up to the thermostat location. This may require pulling a whole new 3 wire cable.

If there's an open terminal where the brown wire attaches to the transformer, you can connect the new `C` wire for the thermostat there.  Otherwise, you'll have to tap in somewhere else.

This image shows how the new thermostat should be connected to the system.

[image: How to wire new thermostat]

> ***WARNING:*** If you don't feel comfortable poking around yourself, don't hesitate to contact a local HVAC tech (or Electrician).

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow up if I decide to do it myself